# I can pass my data to my database. It shows me this error: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'item_name' doesn't have a default value

Tags: php, laravel

This is my model
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IHAMk.png)

This is my Controller
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0OYP.png)

This is my Route

```
    Route::post('consultation_form', [ConsultationController::class,'addConsultation']);
```

Comment: This generally means in the schema for your database the field `item_name` does not have the nullable attribute and there is no data being passed into it.

In your migration add the `->nullable()` attribute on the field.

Comment: share code via txt, not images. also, in this case, share ur migration for that table

Answer (score 1):

This means your not providing a value for the item_name field when you are trying to insert a record for the consultation model.

The input being provided is most likely empty, and MYSQL is giving you an error because your database wasn't setup for that field to have a default value when one isn't provided.

Answer (score 0):

Put

```
$table->string('item_name')->nullable();
```

Or if you want a default name.

```
$table->string('item_name')->default('item_default_name);
```